# Is there a 'QGIS Browser' app on mac?

Tags: qgis, mac

Starting at 1.8, there's a standalone Quantum GIS Browser application on Windows. I am unable to  locate that app on Mac. There is a 'Browser' panel for Mac but its functionality is limited.

Comment: When did you download your installer btw?

Comment: I got the installers from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> QGIS Browser.app is located in QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin. For ease
>   of launching, make a symlink or Finder alias to it.

from https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/pull/197

Comment: got it. thanks. Would be nice to have it more discoverable...